# How to put an executable script on the background and wake it up after x minutes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm developing a timer in bash and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "For how long should I sleep? "
read answer
minutes=$((answer * 60))
sleep $answer && echo foo
```

It works like I was expecting except that I have to wait the X minutes I passed as input to get the prompt back.

Any ideas how I can execute this and have it execute it in the background so I can keep working with my terminal without waiting for script to finish?

Comment: You can also use crontab to trigger the .sh file if needed to run at certain intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an & to the end of last line. That is:

```
sleep $answer && echo foo &
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put a `sleep` and `echo` in the background, like so:

```
$ { sleep 30; echo awake; } &
```

Or you can make a function too:

```
$ remind () { sleep $(($1 * 60)); shift; echo "$@"; }
$ remind 15 'check on dinner' &
[1] 28336
$ # more work...
# later...
$ check on dinner
[1]+  Done                    remind 15 'check on dinner'
```

Answer (score 1):

After you answer the prompt, suspend the script with <kbd>Control-z</kbd>. Then restart it in the background with `bg`.

Comment: but if I get it suspended then the time wouldn't be counting right?

Comment: Sure it would. When you do `sleep N`, it calculates the time `N` seconds later, and then schedules a timer alarm at that time. Suspending the process doesn't change that.